# How to restore gsutil command?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gsutil

I have updated Google Cloud SDK to the latest version 135.0.0 from

After the update , I got the following message.

> WARNING: There are older versions of Google Cloud Platform tools on
> your system PATH. Please remove the following to avoid accidentally
> invoking these old tools:
>
> /usr/bin/git-credential-gcloud.sh
>
> /usr/bin/bq
>
> /usr/bin/gcloud
>
> /usr/bin/gsutil

So I have deleted all the above folders.

After that **gsutil** stopped working.

Please help me how can I resolve the issue.

Comment: How was the older version installed and how did you update to latest?

Comment: It was pre-installed in VM(virtual machine)'s ssh. After few days it prompted for the update , and I pressed yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that it was installed via

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk
```

see 
  https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/#deb
and you should have used the same mechanism to upgrade.

gcloud is also kind of a package manager, and is able to upgrade itself and its depended packages. Unfortunately if you use gcloud itself to upgrade it installs it in different location. It likely does not work because new location needs to be added to your path.

You can try to reinstall googcle-cloud-sdk package via apt-get.